# In an Airbus A-320, when is it appropriate to use: vertical speed mode, the expedite button, and the speedbrake?

Tags: airbus-a320, pilot-technique

When it is appropriate and good airmanship to use Vertical speed on A-320 and where it is written?

Also same questions for the speedbrake?

Also, why do some captains call the expedite push button the "killer button"?